# SaveAs dialog store in recent folder

Tags: vba, ms-word, save-as

I have created some small macro, which changes the filename before the "SaveAs" dialog is called, everything works fine, except when the user selects a "recent folder", the dialog still suggests to  store it in default document folder, instead of the chosen folder.[Chose Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjVuI.png),  [Save As Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0oyP.png)

The function is saving the file fine, with my suggested name. 
My issue is, if a user click the folder with read mark here, I expect that my Save As Dialog will refer to this folder instead of the default folder (C:\User\Documents). [Choose specific folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlP0S.png)

The function Application.Filedialog removes other functionality like the takes and other document properties, which is also needed.

```
Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    If (SaveAsUI = False And ScHasDocumentBeenSaved = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate <> "Normal.dotm") Then
        Dim intChoice As Integer
        Dim strPath As String

        If (HasDocumentBeenSaved = False) Then
            With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
                .name = SpecializedHelper.FileName
                .Show
            End With
        Else
            ActiveDocument.Save
        End If

        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use `Application.FileDialog` property instead. There you could define suggested path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save As not saving a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930845/save-as-not-saving-a-file)

Comment: None of them are solving my issue. I have added more text to my question

Comment: I tried to solve your problem and ran up against questions I couldn't answer. (1) Is it correct that you wish to provide a file name generated by a function and use the dialog only to pick the destination folder? Of course, you might enter the file name in the dialog box. (2) Is it correct that you wish to subject only documents to this treatment which have never been saved AND aren't based on the Normal template?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my documents are based on other templates than normal.dotm.  this dialog box provide all save functionality.  My only outstanding is getting the path a user choose before the dialog is opened.